# Ionic View is not Updating with Two way Data Binding

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-view

I am creating very basic ionic app.  I want to show splash, then admob interstitial and on close of interstitial, i want to redirect to home page.

The only problem which I am facing here is updating the view in the home page.  In home page, i have very simple text box and button.  I am using 2 way data binding here and its not working at all.

I have created repo for this if somebody wants to have a look and let me know why the view is not updating.

```
https://github.com/krishnaa99/admobissue
```

Demo Video

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t_BKJ1mGpag
```

Comment: just added demo video of the issue

Answer (score 1):

if the value is changing in component but not in view(html) then after action in component use this.

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
constructor(private changeRef: ChangeDetectorRef){}
this.changeRef.detectChanges();
```

i hope it can help.

Comment: this seems to help, thanks, could you maybe explain a bit more on why this is or why the components does not catch all changes, in my case its a onended callback.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions you can try

- you should check the logs for errors
- Assign clear type to "input" variable. ( try making it explicitly
  public )
- "input" may be considered as a keyword, try using a different
  variable name ( less likely )

Comment: I tried everything, thats why i have added link to git repo plus demo video. Can you have a look over gitrepo and let me knw whats wrong?